# Does rsync support hot transfer while the system is running?

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, luks, clone

I want to use `rsync` for creating complete, bootable backups of a LUKS-encrypted Linux disk. Does it support hot-transferring of files, i.e. can I use `rsync` from a running (idling) system with opened files, processes etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There is rarely exclusive file locking as there is on Windows systems. The up side of this is that it's easy to copy files that are open by other processes - even files that are being written. The down side is that it's easy to copy files that are open by other processes and that are being written.

`rsync` does notice when a file it's copying has been updated underneath it, and will fail the copy of that file. A re-run will usually succeed - provided of course that the file isn't still being updated.

Remember `rsync -a` to ensure you copy timestamps and permissions. Also be aware that `rsync` between two local devices/filesystems is nowhere near as efficient as copying between two systems. It trades network efficiency for disk efficiency.

Comment: Perfect, thx! :)  By efficiency I assume that you mean transfer speed? And if I use `rsync -a` to duplicate an entire file system (such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png)), will the backup be "complete" in the sense that e.g. all system and security settings, network configurations (proxies, VPNs), user/group policies etc. will be faithfully preserved? I understand that components outside the file system (bootloader, partition information) need to be replicated by other means...

Comment: Note: [**This**](https://superuser.com/a/307542/941977) answer gives some more userful `rsync` options/flags to widen its scope