# Using rsync to create a complete OS backup/clone sufficient?

Tags: rsync, backup, luks, restore, cloning

Will using `rsync` to duplicate an entire file system, e.g. doing

`rsync -avxHAX --progress / /dev/[backup disk]`

as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/307542/941977), result in a **complete** duplicate Linux system? I.e. will all system and security settings, network configurations (proxies, VPNs), user/group policies etc. be faithfully reproduced or is there anything - apart from things outside the file system (bootloader, partition tables) - that `rsync` will miss?

What if the source disk is LUKS-encrypted ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png)), i.e. doing

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[source disk] && rsync -avxHAX --progress / /dev/[backup disk]`?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't work at all.

You should send it to a mounted filesystem, so not `/dev/[backup disk]` but something like `/mnt/[backup disk]/` after doing `mount /dev/[backup disk] /mnt/[backup disk]`

Furthermore, if you have multiple 'real' filesystems (ext4, btrfs, zfs, ...) you will also miss those.
If you run `mount | grep \/dev\/sd` you can, in most cases see all the ones you have.
(There are exceptions: filesystems that are not mounted at the moment, filesystems that are not a /dev/sd*X* device, ...)

**Edit:** I didn't answer the 2nd question. The same problem here, and the same fix would apply.
BUT: If the destination filesystem doesn't use encryption everything will be saved decrypted

Comment: Not only that, by trying to take an image of the live, mounted root filesystem there's no guarantee that the image is coherent and consistent.

Comment: Thx for the answer/replies! Gee, that's a huge disappointment. It was suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599850/311155) that `rsync` supports hot-transferring of file trees. In the case of the above-mentioned [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sAl.png), what would then be a "canonical" way to duplicate the file system?

Comment: @Garo: What's the difference between just sending everything e.g. to a USB flash drive and first mounting it? Won't plugging in the pen drive usually automatically mount it?

Comment: `rsync` does indeed do a hot-transfer but that doesn't mean that during the rsync files don't change on your source. That being said, on pretty much every desktop, `rsync -avxHAX --progress / /mnt/extradisk/` will indeed do exactly what you want. (If you have a extradisk with a partition with one of the default Linux filesystems mounted on /mnt/extradisk). See `man rsync` for the full info to get a idea what actually happens to see if it will work in your case

Comment: I don't really understand the question about the usb flash drive. On most systems it will indeed mount it automatically. But that does not mean you can just use `/dev/[usb flashdrive]` as a destination ! The 'files' in `/dev` are always representations of the disk it self, not of the mount point ! Run a `mount | grep usb_flash_drive` to find out the mount point.

Comment: @Garo: Thank you for this important correction! I need to do some reading on `/dev` vs `/mnt` as I don't quite understand the difference. When e.g. wiping a drive by doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`, zeros are written to `/dev/sdX` and not `/mnt/sdX` - at least from the syntax

Comment: This is what I get from `mount | grep \/dev\/sd`: `/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)`

Comment: @AndrewHenle: You're right, but AFAIK `rsync` is designed to handle this issue, it knows when files are being changed while copying and will do an update afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do it with `rsync`. But why bother doing it manually?

To make a complete copy of the OS the best tool would be `Timeshift` (it is offered by Debian and its offsprings, probably others too). It will create a complete copy of everything needed for a full backup-restore. Under the hood, the `Timeshift` will use `rsync`, but it already knows all pieces of OS which are required for complete copy.

Comment: Thanks for this bit! Does `Timeshift` also create standalone backups, i.e. will the backup be bootable by itself?

Comment: No, the backup is not bootable by itself. But you can boot from LiveCD and (assuming you have the same structure of partitions on your HDD) you can restore the backup on a new machine.

Comment: [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) appears to exclude the home directory ("User files such as documents, pictures and music are excluded"), therefore an additional tool is required for a 'complete' backup in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking two different questions.

Will rsync copy/duplicate a file system?  Yes it will.  It can also be used to convert between file systems (you can copy an ext3 filesystem into a ext4 partition for instance).  The file systems need to support each others features: copying ext4 into fat will lose a lot of functionality.  You do need to mount the file systems; I am assuming you know how to do that.  You also can usually get the live CDs to mount the file systems for you then press Control-Alt-T to open a command prompt.

I'm not familiar with LUKS; I expect that if you can mount the filesystem such that the files can be read that it will copy.

Your original question also asks about a clone.  The copy you make with rsync will almost certainly not boot.  You need to do a couple more steps.

If the partitions have changed, you will need to modify /etc/fstab.  If your existing system is using UUIDs to identify the partitions, you will need to modify fstab.  You can change it back to the old non-UUID style if you want; that makes it easier to clone but it is not recommended.

Updated to add: recent debian kernel changes (some time mid-2022) no longer support non-UUID designations in fstab for boot devices.  You must provide a UUID for the partition to be bootable.

Then you will need to add boot code.  You will need to use chroot to modify the target system.  Most commonly grub2 is installed.  The best examples I've found are here: [Ubuntu community help on grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

And because links move around, I'll gratuitously copy some examples:

this is a way to install grub

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt # Example: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX # Example: sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

And to update the directory of images in grub:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with rsync alone.
You should first make a backup of the entire system. I personally use an rsync wrapper ([Butterfly Backup](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/Butterfly-Backup)) to do this. Here is an example:

```
$ bb backup --computer mypc --destination /backup --data System --type Unix
```

Then you should install a new machine and do a restore like this:

```
$ bb restore --catalog /backup --last --computer mypc
```

This way you brought the necessary files (passwd, etc) to the new system without touching special files like `/dev`

Comment: You have suggested this same software in answers three times in an hour. Your user account has so far _only been used to promote this software_. Are you associated with the software in any shape or form?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion